# Something is already running on port 3001

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd

When I run react application in CMD. My output appeared as "Something is already running on port 3001".
[image]

But I need to run my application on the 3001 port.
After I checked the 3001 port using netstat -ano | findstr 3001 command. Then there is no output.
[image]

How I kill that process?

Comment: `netstat -aof | findstr :3001` or run `resmon.exe` > Listening Ports

Comment: @PsyGik Still same issue...

Comment: Even in Resource Monitor you couldn't find the port? As a last resort, try restarting the system.

Comment: I tried it several times issue is still the same...

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a pre-used port might not be flagged as released even though it isn't actually used.

If closing all the node instances did not help(as suggested by Ashish Bairwa), try restarting the machine.
Then try the following command in CMD to reserve the port, so that there won't be any issues in the future.

```
    netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=3001 numberofports=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a colon i guess.

Try this: `netstat -ano | findstr :3001`

Comment: Still not working... There is no output for this command.

Comment: Interesting, can you kill all your node instances from task manager and try again?

Comment: Also can you please look at the extended log returned by netstat -a -o -n and try to find processes for port 3001 manually via search.

Comment: This process I tried before also. There are not 3001 port